# Подскажите что за "синтаксис" такой и как подобный создать в C#

Tags: c#

наткнулся на такой код в C# подскажите что это за синтаксис такой? И как можно построить такую конструкцию?

`project.Variables["parametr"].Value = "значение-1";`

вот есть пример где подобные конструкция встречаются (строка 28) [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KHzARJ)

Comment: Это называется индексатор.

Comment: Построить конструкцию чего? В коде, который по ссылке, все показано. Что именно вы хотите? Там используется `HtmlAgilityPack` и его `HtmlNodeCollection`. Что именно вам непонятно? Квадратные скобки, обращение через точку, символ равно, или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем вам это. Обычно код пишут с какой-то целью и задают конкретные вопросы.

Но если очень хочется, то вот.

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyProject project = new MyProject();
        project.Variables = new Dictionary<string, MyVariable>();
        project.Variables.Add("parameter", new MyVariable());

        project.Variables["parameter"].Value = "Hello World!";

        Console.WriteLine(project.Variables["parameter"].Value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyProject
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyVariable> Variables { get; set; }
}

public class MyVariable
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Hello World!
```

Чтобы разобраться, как это работает, вам нужно изучить:

- [Объекты и классы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/introduction-to-classes)
- [Поля](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) и [Свойства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)
- [Коллекции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections)
- [Индексаторы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)
- [Словари](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо)